# Has a small group ever made or attempted a false flag against a government?

Tags: government

I think it's common for governments to make [false flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) against small groups, but has it ever happened the other way?

Has some small militia or some other civilian group made some attack and attributed it to the government that was in power at the time?

I know that pirates used to use the flags of countries on their ship, and that can make it look like the country was the one doing the pirating, but now it is more common for governments to attack civilian targets and blame it on people (for example from the middle east).

But I wonder whether there is an example of a small militia that has attacked civilians and made it look like the government did it, as a way to step up and take over the government.

Comment: Welcome to History.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your own research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please clarify who 'did' the attribution in your assumption: the small group or the general audience? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to also comply better with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [How to ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Could you back up your assertions?  If it is important to your question, then please provide research to prove that governments are employing false flags. If it is not important to your question, I would advise you to remove those assertions.

Comment: Does the Boston Tea Party count? Or "I shall return?"  What about small team's actions against foreign governments (Russia and China both claim that cyber attacks are the actions of private individuals.)

Comment: What about Wilhem Voight? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Voigt

Comment: False flag operations are hard to prove. Some sources, such as Seymour Hersh, say that some of the gas attacks in Syria are false flag operations by jihadists trying to make western powers more involved in the syrian civil war, but the evidences are fuzzy at best.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the Lavon-Affair would count as such https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavon_Affair